# Get data to labelbox via cloud function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I want to write a Google Cloud Function to retrieve data from a bucket and upload it to Labelbox. Here's the function code:

```
import labelbox
from labelbox import Client, Dataset
import os
import uuid
import logging

# Add your API key below
LABELBOX_API_KEY = "my api key"
client = Client(api_key=LABELBOX_API_KEY)

def upload_asset(event, context):
    """Uploads an asset to Catalog when a new asset is uploaded to GCP bucket. 
       If a dataset with bucket_name exists in Catalog, then an asset is added to that dataset. Otherwise, a new dataset is created.
    Args:
         event (dict): Event payload.
         context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
    """
    file = event
    bucket_name = file['bucket']
    object_name = file["name"]
    
    try:
        datasets = client.get_datasets(where=Dataset.name == bucket_name)
        dataset = next(datasets, None)
        if not dataset:
            dataset = client.create_dataset(name=bucket_name)
        url = f"gs://{bucket_name}/{object_name}"
        dataset.create_data_row(row_data=url, external_id=object_name )
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        return "success"
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return "failure"
```

this gives Forbidden error in labelbox side how to fix that

I wrote a Google Cloud Function in Python to read data from a Google Cloud Storage bucket and upload it to Labelbox using the Labelbox Python SDK. I expected the function to run without errors and upload the data to my Labelbox project.

However, when I triggered the function, I received a "Forbidden" error message in Labelbox, and the function did not complete successfully. The error message indicated that Labelbox was unable to authenticate my request, but I'm not sure what's causing the problem.

I've checked that my Labelbox API key is correct and that I have the necessary permissions to upload data to my Labelbox project. I've also confirmed that my Google Cloud Function is able to read the data from the bucket successfully.

I'm not sure what else to try to fix this issue. Can you help me understand what might be causing the "Forbidden" error and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

#### Forbidden as a response SDK/API

If you are seeing forbidden as a response from the API, I would try to run the same exact script locally to make sure that the script is working as expected. Also just to make sure you are doing this correctly, and there is no ambiguity around which Delegated Access setup is used I would add the `integration` parameter to your `create_dataset` function call.

Here is how that part of the code would look after adding the integration:

```
...
if not dataset:
   integrations = client.get_organization().get_iam_integrations()
   integration = [
     integration for integration in integrations if 'integration-name' in integration.name
   ][0]
   dataset = client.create_dataset(name=bucket_name, integration=integration)
...
```

#### Forbidden in Catalog or Labelbox UI when labeling/reviewing

If you are seeing the `Forbidden` response from the Labelbox UI then you could be looking at an issue beyond this function and that is that the Delegated Access that was setup is missing the correct CORS config, in that case, I would do back, and check the GCS cors configuration to make sure the correct URLs are being accessed.

I'm happy to make more suggestions if these do not work!